# How to dynamically route the request from client to microservices

Tags: microservices, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

Here is what I am trying to achieve :
   1. I have a sets of micro-service of same type with different versions. E.g. set-1 of account(ms1-v1, ms2-v1, ms3-v1) and set-2 of account(ms1-v2, ms2-v2, ms3-v2)
      Here, all services in set-1 is of version v1 and set-2 of version v2
   2. I want to use Netflix Zuul to select a micro-service instance of account on the basis of version that is specified in a request.

For example, if a request comes from a client that wants to access account service of version v1. Step 2 above should return me anyone among ms1-v1, ms2-v1 and ms3-v1. In each request version would be part of request header.

We use ribbon for client side load-balancing

Thanks a lot in advance.